# Any need to connect iOS device to iTunes?

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud

My home iMac (mid-2006) finally died a few weeks ago. We have a variety of iOS devices (2 iPhones/3 iPads). They all backup to iCloud and have iTunes Match. Once I get a new Mac for the house, will there be any reason to register/sync these devices with iTunes on the new computer? It seems with over-the-air app and iOS updates, iCloud backup, and iTunes match there isn't a reason anymore. Am I right about this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use iTunes Match, so I still sync music the old fashioned way, but I can't think of another reason I'd ever sync my device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are. With iOS 7 Apple really has worked hard to make sure that iDevices were an option for people with no other "regular" computer. You can redownload from Apple and back up pictures to iCloud but be aware that you might want to have the ability to get the pictures off a different way (such as a upgraded Dropbox account with 100 GBs) but otherwise keeping things in e-mails and using applications with online storage you should be totally fine.